# Should I separate current users and potential customers?

Tags: login, marketing, landing-page

My company is a B2B Software as a Service. We have a web with 2 main functions:

1. Log in for my current **users** (hundred of thousands)
2. a marketing web for my potential new customers, (portfolio, blog, contact us, etc.), about hundred **leads**.

It is recommended to put a first landing page to asking if who is in the browser is a current **user** or a **lead**, and depending on it, redirect to different webs?

I think it can improve the web optimization for each audience, and help keeping separated metrics (Analytics), but can be hard for who is browsing to give an additional click for accessing the page.

Comment: I'll note that you can, with decent (but not perfect) reliability, detect if a user is a current user.  E.g., leave a "this is a logged out user" cookie behind when users log out.

Comment: I'll note that you can, with decent (but not perfect) reliability, detect if a user is a current user.  E.g., leave a "this is a logged out user" cookie behind when users log out.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's much value in having a dedicated gateway page forcing the user to choose between 'new user' and 'existing user'. It's a detrimental extra step for both audiences, particularly for new users. Instead, let everyone go to your marketing site, and include a prominent link for existing users to sign-in at the top.

Answer (score 0):

If the primary goal is actually to improve the web optimization for each audience and to help keep separated metrics (Analytics), then I think it would be a very good approach to create a dialogue that let's a current user or a lead decide which webpage best suits them.

However, it would be advisable to make the landing page interactive so that the user doesn't find the extra step in choosing the personalized  site tedious.